# Javascript modify array objects property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties

So I have an array, where I am trying to update an objects property value, like so:

```
        this.tasks[5].status = "complete";

   // Here is the object looks like when I log it:
    {"rowID":16,"task":"and more stuff","status":"incomplete","inlist":"Homework"}
```

Yet the above code does not change the value, it does nothing. Is my syntax wrong, or is there something else in my code causing this?

It seems I can add properties to the object, but I cant modify existing ones. I also can delete the object, but cant delete a property from it.

Thanks

Comment: `this.tasks` might be an array, but does its `1` property reference an object? And if so, what kind of object? Is its *status* property readonly? You need to tell us a bit more about it.

Comment: first guess: are you trying to change the value of the first array object?  arrays are 0 index based meaning the first item in the array is this.tasks[0]

Comment: Also providing the declaration of tasks would be most helpful in answering your question

Comment: Yes the array object and property do exist. I will post a full array object string. @joseph that was just my example value, the oject I am modifying does exist.

Comment: @RobG, It does reference an object. I think it has write access, cause I am able to remove (splice) the object from the array.

Comment: have you tried `this.tasks[5]["status"] = "complete";`?

Comment: just typed this into chrome's console 
`a = [{"property": "value"}]`
`a[0].property = "new value"`
`a[0].property` is now `"new value"`
seems that you might have another problem besides the syntax

Comment: @ilia choly When I do that, it creates a new property with the value of status as the key. Like so: "incomplete": "complete"

Comment: Would you mind providing the output of `console.log(this.tasks[5]);`?

Comment: @ Lance. It outputs the object you see at the bottom of my post. It seems I can add properties to the object, but I cant modify existing ones. I also can delete the object, but cant delete a property from it.

Comment: @levi something else is wrong with your code. http://i.imgur.com/key7t.png <--- Chrome & http://i.imgur.com/UTpMq.png <--- IE9 have a look at those console pics. Everything works exactly as you expect. I believe you need to provide *_more_* information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be something else in your code. Here are two pics of your setup working in both Chrome and IE9.

[Chrome Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr3wW.png)

[IE9 Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isgY9.png)

Comment: Thanks. Time to start debugging.